# How do I access the querystring in an Umbraco template?

Tags: templates, url, umbraco

I'm trying to get hold of the querystring directly from the template in Umbraco, but can't seem to figure it out..

For example:
/mypage.aspx?p=bek

I can do it with <%=HttpContext.Current.Request["p"]%>, but I want it in a field...

Something like this:

Any ideas?

Comment: Yep, I was just about to answer with that same solution.  Looks good.

Comment: This looks like it may leave your site vulnerable to XSS attacks. In that you are reflecting un-validated input to the page. Worth checking that your code doesn't leave you open to this. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: Good point Tim.  Would umbraco.library:RequestQueryString('Yourstring') be safer?  Does it do any XSS checking?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys!
Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi bek, ASP.NET includes XSS checking by default for <script> and other malicious input, which you can disable by changing the <pages> validateRequest attribute to "false" in your web.config.

Comment: Bek could you post your update as an answer, so it's clear the question has actually been answered. You might even get some Karma for it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I fixed it.

Found this:
http://forum.umbraco.org/yaf_postst6663_Get-querystring-in-template.aspx

If anyone else is interested, you do the following..
Create a xslt file with the name "QueryStringExtractor" and paste the below code where it belongs.

```
<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>
<xsl:variable name="yourvalue" select="//macro/myparam" />

<xsl:template match="/">

<!-- start writing XSLT -->
<xsl:value-of select="$yourvalue" />

</xsl:template>
```

Save and update the Umbraco page and you'll see a macro under "Macros" with the same namne.
In the macro you add the parameter "myparam" (I put it as text). Save!

Then in your template just past the following code and you're good to go!

```
<ul>
    <umbraco:Macro Alias="QueryStringExtractor" myparam="[@p]" runat="server"></umbraco:Macro>
</ul>
```

So now when you enter the querystring "?p=something" you'll get "something" written on the page.

Notice that you can pass any "p" to the macro.

Hope this helps someone else!